# Issue with build C# proj in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build a project that was originally made in Visual Studio 2013, in Visual Studio 2017, but now getting this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\Debug.resources"

it refers to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    2865

I tried clean, build, rebuild, manual deletion...

I could not find any helpful info.
any idea guys?

Thanks,

Comment: Try Rebuild. That deletes the contents of the debug folder

Comment: yep. clean, build, rebuild, manual deletion of bin and Debug.....

Comment: What about deleting and adding any non-system references or resources so they point to the correct directory?

Comment: it's quite a big project with many references, so not sure it is the safest way to go,,,,,

Comment: @Gil404, what is your project type? It seems like maybe you have a duplicate resource file. So please check you project file whether have duplicate resource file or not. If yes, delete it, then rebuild project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739794/two-output-file-names-resolved-to-the-same-output. If this not works for you, would you mind sharing us the project file?